# Derivation of linear function (simple question)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I need some help with the following:

Let $K: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ be linear and $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$.

If $f(x) := K(x) + b, f: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$, how can I show that $Df(x) = K(x)$ (for $x \in \mathbb{R}^m$)?!

I tried using the definition;
so $f$ is differentiable if there exists a linear function $K: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ so that:

$\lim\limits_{h \to 0} {\dfrac{f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0) - L(h)}{h}} = 0$

so for $L(h)$ I can choose $K(h)$ and see if the $\lim$ is $0$?

So:

$\lim\limits_{h \to 0} {\dfrac{K(x_0+h)+b)-(K(x_0)+b) - K(x)}{h}} = \lim\limits_{h \to 0} {\dfrac{K(h)-K(x)}{h}}$ ?!

Comment: Hint: in your last equation, not $-K(x)$ but $-K(h)$...

Answer (score 1):

The first limit in your last equation is wrong.

It should be

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(K(x_0+h)+b)-(K(x_0)+b) - K(h)}{\|h\|}$$

can you see why? And can you conclude with this correction?

Comment: The whole thing is wrong, $h$ is supposed to be a vector.

Comment: @GitGud right... it should be the norm of $h$ in the denominator.

Comment: Ok, now with $lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(K(x_0 + h) + b) - (K(x_0)+b)-K(h)}{||h||} = lim_{h \to 0} \frac{K(h) - K(h)}{||h||} = 0$ I'm done?

Comment: @Vazrael yes you are. Since the differential of $f$ is unique (because $f$ is differentiable), you must have $Df=K$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: First show that the total derivative $DK$ of a linear transformation $K:\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R^m$ is the linear transformation $K$ itself and the total derivative of a constant function is zero. From this conclude that $Df=D(K+b)=DK=K.$